# Как переопределить метод getDescription() в Joomla?

Tags: joomla, php

Есть вопрос по CMS Joomla 3.15.
Есть в Joomla метод `$document->getDescription();`, который берет из статьи первые 200 символов и вставляет их в meta тег description. Как мне переопределить этот метод, чтобы он брал первые 300 символов из статьи? И где можно найти, где описывается этот метод? В каком файле?

```
/**
     * Generates the head HTML and return the results as a string
     *
     * @param   JDocument  $document  The document for which the head will be created
     *
     * @return  string  The head hTML
     *
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public function fetchHead($document)
    {
        // Convert the tagids to titles
        if (isset($document->_metaTags['standard']['tags']))
        {
            $tagsHelper = new JHelperTags;
            $document->_metaTags['standard']['tags'] = implode(', ', $tagsHelper->getTagNames($document->_metaTags['standard']['tags']));
        }

        // Trigger the onBeforeCompileHead event
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $app->triggerEvent('onBeforeCompileHead');

        // Get line endings
        $lnEnd = $document->_getLineEnd();
        $tab = $document->_getTab();
        $tagEnd = ' />';
        $buffer = '';

        // Generate charset when using HTML5 (should happen first)
        if ($document->isHtml5())
        {
            $buffer .= $tab . '<meta charset="' . $document->getCharset() . '" />' . $lnEnd;
        }

        // Generate base tag (need to happen early)
        $base = $document->getBase();
        if (!empty($base))
        {
            $buffer .= $tab . '<base href="' . $document->getBase() . '" />' . $lnEnd;
        }

        // Generate META tags (needs to happen as early as possible in the head)
        foreach ($document->_metaTags as $type => $tag)
        {
            foreach ($tag as $name => $content)
            {
                if ($type == 'http-equiv' && !($document->isHtml5() && $name == 'content-type'))
                {
                    $buffer .= $tab . '<meta http-equiv="' . $name . '" content="' . htmlspecialchars($content) . '" />' . $lnEnd;
                }
                elseif ($type == 'standard' && !empty($content))
                {
                    $buffer .= $tab . '<meta name="' . $name . '" content="' . htmlspecialchars($content) . '" />' . $lnEnd;
                }
            }
        }

        // Don't add empty descriptions
        $documentDescription = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($document->getDescription()));
        //echo $documentDescription;
        if ($documentDescription)
        {
            $buffer .= $tab . '<meta name="description" content="' . $documentDescription . '" />' . $lnEnd;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще мысль пришла: возможно, description записывается в базу при сохранении, изменении странички. Так вот у поля может стоять длина 200 символов), поэтому даже если на сервер пойдет 300, 400 или 1000 символов, то все обрежется до 200.
Глянь на структуру БД.

C Джумлой не работал))
Но смотрим [тут](http://www.reference.joomlademo.de/nav.html).

Открываем libraries/joomla/document/ -> document.php (summary).
Смотрим файлик, описывающий данный класс)
Вот сам метод - тут ничего интересного:

```
  /**
 789       * Return the title of the page.
 790       *
 791       * @return  string
 792       *
 793       * @since    11.1
 794       */
 795    public function getDescription()
 796      {
 797          return $this->description;
 798      }
```

Ищем тут:

```
public function setDescription($description)
 782      {
 783          $this->description = $description;
 784  
 785          return $this;
 786      }
```

Тоже ничего(
Ищем дальше:

```
/**
 417       * Sets or alters a meta tag.
 418       *
 419       * @param   string   $name        Value of name or http-equiv tag
 420       * @param   string   $content     Value of the content tag
 421       * @param   boolean  $http_equiv  META type "http-equiv" defaults to null
 422       *
 423       * @return  JDocument instance of $this to allow chaining
 424       *
 425       * @since   11.1
 426       */
 427    public function setMetaData($name, $content, $http_equiv = false)
 428      {
 429          $name = strtolower($name);
 430  
 431          if ($name == 'generator')
 432          {
 433              $this->setGenerator($content);
 434          }
 435          elseif ($name == 'description')
 436          {
 437              $this->setDescription($content);
 438          }
 439          else
 440          {
 441              if ($http_equiv == true)
 442              {
 443                  $this->_metaTags['http-equiv'][$name] = $content;
 444              }
 445              else
 446              {
 447                  $this->_metaTags['standard'][$name] = $content;
 448              }
 449          }
 450  
 451          return $this;
 452      }
```

В коде есть вызов данного метода? Посмотри, как туда переменная `$content` попадает?

Comment: В коде нет вызова метода setMetaData(), вот переменная $content присваивается через foreach:
foreach ($document->_metaTags as $type => $tag)
 {
 foreach ($tag as $name => $content)
  {
  if ($type == 'http-equiv' && !($document->isHtml5() && $name == 'content-type'))
   {
    $buffer .= $tab . '<meta http-equiv="' . $name . '" content="' . htmlspecialchars($content) . '" />' . $lnEnd;
   }
  elseif ($type == 'standard' && !empty($content))
   {
    $buffer .= $tab . '<meta name="' . $name . '" content="' . htmlspecialchars($content) . '" />' . $lnEnd;
   }
  }
 }

Comment: А можно весь код глянуть от момента создания `$document` до вызова `$document->getDescription();,`

Comment: @Ale_x, добавил нужный кусок кода в вопрос, буду благодарен, если поможете разобраться. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Это вы мне реализацию класса дали, правда, не указано, какого). Где в вашем коде идет создание переменной $document?

Comment: @Ale_x, не могу найти, где создается объект $document или присваивается переменная $document. Как быть?

Comment: вот тут есть плагин http://tushov.ru/post/374 он меняет длину) 
а вообще зачем те 300 символов) на просторах инета пишут что поисковиками  обрабатываются первые 150-200 символов

Comment: @Ale_x, дело в том, что он берет в эти 200 символов всю HTML-разметку, которая идет перед текстом, поэтому нужно брать символов 300-400 и вырезать HTML-теги из выборки.